# jsTree Showing root node when populating from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jstree

I have a requirement to show the root node in jsTree when using the php/mysql implementation. All the relevant code is below along with screen shots of the output.

Current table structure: (sorry can't embed images yet...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pig1V.jpg

Current output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4F8G.jpg

As you can see the actual root node called ROOT is not shown in the tree. The various snippets of code that displays the above is:

javascript:

```
.jstree({
    // List of active plugins
    "plugins" : [ 
        "themes","json_data","ui","crrm","dnd","search","types","hotkeys","contextmenu" 
    ],

    // I usually configure the plugin that handles the data first
    // This example uses JSON as it is most common
    "json_data" : { 
        // This tree is ajax enabled - as this is most common, and maybe a bit more complex
        // All the options are almost the same as jQuery's AJAX (read the docs)
        "ajax" : {
            // the URL to fetch the data
            "url" : "_demo/server2.php",
            // the `data` function is executed in the instance's scope
            // the parameter is the node being loaded 
            // (may be -1, 0, or undefined when loading the root nodes)
            "data" : function (n) { 
                // the result is fed to the AJAX request `data` option
                return {

                    "operation" : "get_children", 
                    "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_","") : 1

                }; 
            }
        }
    },
```

PHP:

```
function get_children($data) {
    $tmp = $this->_get_children((int)$data["id"]);
    if((int)$data["id"] === 1 && count($tmp) === 0) {
        ## - No data returned
    }
    $result = array();
    if((int)$data["id"] === 0) return json_encode($result);
    foreach($tmp as $k => $v) {
        $result[] = array(
            "just_id" => $k,
            "attr" => array("id" => "node_".$k, "rel" => $v[$this->fields["type"]]),
            "data" => $v[$this->fields["title"]],
            "owner" => $v[$this->fields["owner"]],
            "state" => ((int)$v[$this->fields["right"]] - (int)$v[$this->fields["left"]] > 1) ? "closed" : ""
        );
    }
    return json_encode($result);
}

function _get_children($id, $recursive = false) {
    $hbhbhbh = fSession::get('nodes_allowed[nodes]');
    if (in_array($id, $hbhbhbh)) {

        $children = array();
        if($recursive) {
            $node = $this->_get_node($id);
            $this->db->query("SELECT `".implode("` , `", $this->fields)."` FROM `".$this->table."` WHERE `".$this->fields["left"]."` >= ".(int) $node[$this->fields["left"]]." AND `".$this->fields["right"]."` <= ".(int) $node[$this->fields["right"]]." ORDER BY `".$this->fields["left"]."` ASC");
        }
        else {
            $this->db->query("SELECT `".implode("` , `", $this->fields)."` FROM `".$this->table."` WHERE `".$this->fields["parent_id"]."` = ".(int) $id." AND FIND_IN_SET(".$this->fields["owner"].", '".implode(',', fSession::get('nodes_allowed[nodes_visible]'))."') ORDER BY `".$this->fields["position"]."` ASC");
        }
        while($this->db->nextr()) $children[$this->db->f($this->fields["id"])] = $this->db->get_row("assoc");
        return $children;
    } else {
        $children = array();
        return $children;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the javascript, I am initially requesting node 1 to load. but it only shows the node directly below it. If I initially load another node further down the tree (effectively making that node the root node), it loads all the sub nodes under it, but doesn't show the initial node.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue..

I eventually just added the root node details to the front of the json string returned by the PHP script when the tree is loaded. It then just shows the root node, and loads the leafs via ajax when the user expands it. Simpler than I thought....